# Testing approach for algorithms with complex outputs

Tags: unit-testing, testing

How to test a result of a program that is basically a black box? For example one year ago I had to write a B tree as a homework and I really struggled with testing the correctness. What strategies do you use in such scenarios? Visualization? Robust input-->result sets of testing data? What do you do when it is hard to get such data because the only way how to get them is your proper working program?

EDIT: I think that my question was misunderstood. There was no problem with understanding how B tree works. That is trivial. But writing robust tests for validating its proper functionality is not so trivial. I think that this school problem is  similar to many practical REAL word scenarios and test cases. And sometimes understanding the domain is quite different from delivering working and correct program...

EDIT2: And yes, with B tree it is possible to validate proper behavior with pen and paper. But this is really dirty and not fun :)  This is not working well with problems that requires huge amount of data for their validation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure these answers really capture the problem at hand. A B-tree's input and output aren't any different from those of any other dictionary---but the algorithm performs better, if it's implemented correctly. It's only really got two functions to test (add, and find) so theoretically, "black-box" testing of this single component should be fine. Designing for testability isn't the issue, since no matter how you do it the whole algorithm will be one component.

So the question is: when you have to implement subtle algorithms, the kinds with complicated output that you can't always understand in your head so well, how do you test them? I think there are three different strategies you can use:

1. Black-box test basic functionality. For the B-tree case, this is things like cwash suggested, and also, things like making sure that when you add an item, you can then find it, etc.
2. Test certain invariants that your algorithm should maintain (the B-tree should be balanced, values within nodes should be sorted, etc.)
3. A few, small "pencil-and-paper" tests may be necessary -- work the algorithm out by hand and check that it matches what your code does. But the big-data tests can all be of type 2. These can also be brittle, so unless you need to be really sure about your algorithm, you may want to avoid them.

Comment: Good answer.  I've taken this approach before when solving pretty complicated problems.  The question to me is a little academic in that I don't find myself implementing binary trees on my own very often.  But I have spiked on various unfamiliar APIs and using pencil and paper tests is the only way to start.  Make sure you understand the nuts and bolts of the algorithm by writing a test.  TestNG's Dataprovider works well for things like this.  Here is an example where I've done just this: http://is.gd/19LH0

Comment: Your point about "one component algorithm" is great. It would be great to have options for mocking any method...Or maybe inheritance is the answer for such problem. But it seems strange to have for every tested method different inherited class which overrides desired methods(really crazy "mocking").

Comment: I think the answer to testing component internals--which you do have to do, sometimes--is that you have to have some "white-box" tests, that know about what's inside. In C++, you can do this with friend tests, for instance. These can be brittle, and you should probably avoid them if possible, but if they're necessary, they're necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not grasp the problem at hand, how can you develop a solution to it?  My suggestion would be to understand the domain enough to be able to work out the problem on paper and ensure that your program matches.

Comment: As Brian said, you can't verify the result or even apply the correct solution unless you understand the problem.

Comment: I think you are wrong. You can perfectly understand the domain but any nontrivial software is prone to bug. And sometimes is REALLY hard to realize that. It is quite different when you have a bad validation on customer email and when you have a big input and complex algorihtms that transform it to complex output. You can really well known the domain and what is doing under the hood but YOU_NEED_TO_VERIFY your program. And that is sometimes TRICKY

Comment: It is often tricky.  Testing is often a more time consuming process than actually solving the problem in the first place.  Validating the correctness of your algorithm takes hard work and often I personally go to pen and paper.  Call me old fashioned but stepping through a Business use case and solving it as it would be solved before the program I created is a surefire way to verify your algorithm.  If you need to consult the business stakeholder and get test input/expected results so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Consult with an expert on the subject.

I know if I have a convoluted procedure I'm trying to fix, I have no idea what the output should be after my changes, so I need to consult a fellow developer with more knowledge of the business need, and they are able to verify what I've done is correct.

Comment: Like the experts on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @emddudley : If it's for a B-tree, then sure. However, if it's for a business user aspect, then the expert could be a power user, another developer, a business analyst etc. I wouldn't ask someone on the internet a question about enterprise-specific processes.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on constructing test cases that exercise the functionality of your B-tree algorithm.  I haven't looked at it for years, but I'm fairly sure you'll be able to find a documented sequence of steps to insert a set of values in a specific order, then validate that the leaf nodes are as they should be.  If you construct your testing along these lines, you should be able to prove your implementation is correct.

Comment: There is not any problem with B tree. That is history. But it comes today into my mind when I evaluate some testing strategies in general.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to know there is a balance between testing something to death and doing tests that adequately cover what should be covered.  Edge cases, e.g null inputs or checking inputs are numeric by testing an alphabet character or a punctuation character, are likely most of the tests you'd need.  To complement this there may be one or two common cases to handle to show the program can handle a non-edge case as well.  To cover all valid input in most programs is overkill and would result in an overwhelmingly large amount of tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question you're asking boils down to designing for testability.  Often you get a testable design for free when you test-drive the development of the solution.  But let's face it, when  you're implementing a highly mathematical algorithm, this just doesn't fall out.

To make sure you have a testable design, you need to understand what a seam is.  Then you need to know a few rules of thumb, such as avoiding statics, using polymorphism, and properly decomposing problems and separating concerns.

Watch ["The Clean Code Talks -- Unit Testing" by Misko Hevery](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w), I think it will help you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at it from a requirements point of view, rather than an implementation point of view. Before you write code, you must understand exactly what you want it to do.

Testing and requirements should be a matching pair. If you're having trouble defining tests, maybe it's because the requirements are not well-defined. That in turn implies that you may have bugs that aren't so much implementation bugs, but "lack of clear requirements" bugs. The code writer in that case would be working to a mental list of requirements that he/she thinks is requirements, but can't be sure, and they're not written down for independent understanding and verification.

I've struggled with software where the requirements weren't clear, because the customer couldn't even tell us what they wanted. But when we delivered to them, they sure could tell us then what they didn't like about it! A big part of software engineering is getting the requirements right before the coding begins. This is true on the high-level (overall product, with requirement input from customer) and also the smaller level (modules, individual functions, where requirements are internally defined by software team or individuals). It is still true to some degree I think for iterative development, although the high-level requirements are more fluid.

Answer (score 0):

@Bystrik Jurina,

I often get involved in projects which involve conversions between disparate data formats. Most answers have focused on testing a B-tree or similar algorithm, but it seems that you're looking for a more general answer.

Most of my work is based on the command line. It may sounds like a contradiction, but one of the first tools I use is visualization. I'll write some methods to write out my data structures in a format that's easy to consume. This can (and usually does) include something that's visually clear. But often it also means something that I could easily parse with a smaller test program, or even import into Excel.

I'll start by focusing on the basic outline, and write a program that does the bare minimum of what I need to accomplish. If it's a multi-step process, this might mean implementing one step at a time and validating the results of each step before moving on. Or writing something that works only in specific cases, and then expanding the set of cases where it's expected to work. At first you can validate that the code works in the limited set of cases, such as for known input data. As the project moves forward, you can start logging warnings for cases you might not have tested, or for unexpected types of input data. This has drawbacks, but is a nice approach when you're dealing with a known set of input data

Validation techniques can include formal test cases, or informal programs that work to challenge your assumptions. It could mean writing a basic driver program to exercise the "core" routines. A good example would be to add a record to a database, then read it back and compare the original object against the one loaded from the database.

If you have trouble wrapping your head around the way a program functions, think about what it needs to accomplish. It might be easier to writing code that tests the way different inputs produce different outputs. Producing visualizations is a good help, because the act of deciding how to display the data can make you think about different conditions and focus in on the most critical parts of your data structures.

Often I've found that building a visualization brings me to admit that the way the data is being stored just isn't very clear. For a B-tree, the representation isn't very flexible. But for other cases, you may be using parallel arrays when a nested tree of objects would be more natural.